# Send Apache Kafka messages through localtunnel.me

Tags: apache-kafka, localtunnel

I am new to Apache Kafka and I'm trying to build a Python app which is able to handle Kafka messages. I've set Kafka up to produce and consume messages locally. Now I also want this to work non-locally, so that I can send messages from everywhere to my Python app.

My idea was to just expose the specific port that Kafka is using by using [Localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/). I thought this would just mirror the local messages, so that I can consume them via the generated URL. But surprise, it doesn't work.

I just don't receive any messages at all. Do you have an idea why this is? Do I maybe have to configure the listeners in the Kafka server.properties first?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you'll need to configure `advertised.listeners`  correctly - see https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: Thanks for your response! I added my local IP address now as `advertised.listeners` and left the `listeners` as PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092. I understand this, as that my local broker should listen to all IP addresses and direct them to my broker at my local IP address. 
But when I try this setup, I still can't receive any messages on external consumers. Do you know what might be the issue here?